# Toilet leaking around flange

Tags: toilet

My toilet started leaking over few days.  There is just a little pool of water near the front part of the flange (No, it isn't from me missing when I pee).  It only happens about once a week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are fairly certain that it is coming from under the toilet... you need to pull it up and don't wait.

The leak you can see is less important than what you can't see. If the seal (wax or other) is compromised, it could cause (of could have already caused) damage that will make a simple wax ring install something else entirely...

Comment: I pulled the toilet off and put a new wax seal on it.  It was a good thing I had to disconnect the water supply because the valve seals were leaking.  I didn't think a wax seal would leak.

Comment: @Paul - Neither of those should ever leak unless the toilet is allowed to rock. Shim it, grout it, caulk it, w/e, until it cannot rock.

Comment: i am wondering if it rocked.